# Using IPMT function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Ipmt function in excel calculates the interest paid in the Nth installment. I wrote a macro to calculate the total interest payable from the first to the Nth installment (which I specify) and put it in the activecell. But the thing is I think somewhere with the array I'm doing it wrong and it results in "Unable to get the IPMT property of the WorksheetFunction class" Error. Could you please help me?

```
Sub CalculateInterest()
Static i As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim PD(1 To 2) As Integer
For j = 1 To 2
i = Application.WorksheetFunction.IPmt(0.18 / 2, PD(j), 2, 108434)
Next j
MsgBox i
ActiveCell.Value = i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the second argument should be

> Per    Required. The period for which you want to find the interest
>   and must be in the range 1 to nper.

In your case, in the range 1 to 2.

Currently it is 0 as you have an array with its initial values of 0,0.

You are also only writing out last value.

Did you mean something like:

```
 i = Application.WorksheetFunction.IPmt(0.18 / 2, j, 2, 108434)
```

To sum as per your comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CalculateInterest()
   ' Static i As Long '<==should this be Long and static?
    Dim i As Double
    Dim j As Long ' <==Use Long rather than Integer
    Dim PD(1 To 2) As Long
    For j = LBound(PD) To UBound(PD)
        i = i + Application.WorksheetFunction.IPmt(0.18 / 2, j, 2, 108434) 'Per should be in range 1 to 2
    Next j
    ActiveCell = i
End Sub
```

Comment: I want the i to calculate the IPMT for 1st per and 2nd per, add them up and then return the sum of IPMT for the 1st and 2nd installment in the active cell. TBH I think my code is far from where I want to get :/

Comment: Thank you @QHarr I appreciate it